# How to add in pom.xml a new block

Tags: java, maven

I have a root `pom.xml` in my study project here it is -
[pom.xml](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hS5zYL5UUgp5KRRR2VfkoWstqMv968-bcx1IyGRtBUk/edit?usp=sharing)

I create the child pom.xml and this line is red --

```
project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
```

here is a full file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>games</artifactId>
        <groupId>ru.job4j</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>puzzle</artifactId>
```

What the problem?

Comment: What line is in red? What did you do, what did you expect, what did you get?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing `</project>` tag at the end of the file.